How to cache data from firestore database in react
Actually I am working on one of my project and  I found that my data is loaded each time I drive back to my data showing page it is not cached or is preloaded also I have used several things before posting this question such as getDocsFromCache and it's other setting to enable the thing also i have tried using Gemini and chatgpt but they are also not good for this  i was not able to do so is here anyone who can give me the steps to actually execute the things correctly
This is my sample code currently it is fetching each time I am coming back to the page after few interval of time and showing the data after hard loading state each time i navigate back to the page i want it to only show the hard loading when I initially open page for first time after that when I navigate back  it should have data preloaded or you can say cached and display all the data from the cache
This is my Component
function Profile() {
 //My custom hook that I created to access the firebase settings and all its functions that i created or are precreated 

  const firebase = useFirebase();
const userRef = collection(firebase.firestore, "users");
const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
const [docId, setDocId] = useState(null);

  const getProfileData = async () => {
    if (firebase.user?.email) {
      const unsubscribe = await getDocs(userRef)
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            if (doc.data().Email === firebase.user?.email) {
              setUserData(doc.data());              

  /*setDocId("'" + doc._key.path.segments[6] + "'")  ;   */

       console.log(doc)          /*console.log("Current user data:", doc.data());*/
            }
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
        });

      return unsubscribe;
    }
  };

  /*const docRef = doc(firebase.firestore, "users", docId);*/

  // Fetch data only if userData is null, preventing unnecessary calls

  /*console.log(userData);*/

useEffect(() => {
  getProfileData();
},[])

    /*console.log(userData);*/

  return (
    <>
      <div className='h-screen w-screen bg-white-900 flex justify-center items-center'>
        <div className='Profile-frame bg-[#740ceb] card-shadow rounded-lg flex  flex-wrap'>
          <div className='bg-white Profile-Img-frame rounded-lg card-shadow m-5 ml-2 mr-0 mb-0 flex justify-center items-center '>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} size='7x' style={{ color: '#740ceb' }} className=' flex items-center justify-center  rounded-lg ' />
          </div>
          <div className='Profile-Text-frame ml-4 mt-5'>

    {userData ? (
      <>
                   {(userData?.ProMember) && (
            <div className='bg-[#FFFFFF]  text-[#740ceb] rounded-lg font-bold w-40 p-0.5 text-center mb-2'>  ProMemberShip </div> )}
            <div className='text-white text-4xl font-bold'> {userData?.Name} </div>
            <div className='fontsize-15px text-white mt-1'>{userData?.Email}</div>
            {(userData?.ProMember === false) && (<button className='bg-[#FFFFFF] text-[#740ceb] rounded-lg button-shadow Upgrade-frame font-bold m-5 ml-3 mt-6 ' onClick={() => To('/ProMember')} >  Upgrade to Pro ✨ </button>)}
      </>
    ):(
      <>
        <div cl> assName = 'text-[#FFFFFF] font-bold '> ...Loading </div>
      </>
    ) }        
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

Help me cache the data that i want here to be displayed or used
As I have said I have tried Ai tools and firebase docs to resolve this out but is still facing issues

To specify the web sdk's behavior, you first need to (in your firebase-config.js file or in the main entry point of your app)
initialize firestore with specific rules.
firebase doc
//firebase-config.js

initializeFirestore(app, 
  {localCache: 
    persistentLocalCache({tabManager: persistentSingleTabManager()})

});

Seen the doc you have other avaible settings.
Just that and by default if you need data and your device is offline you can get data from cache.
Don't forget when you use "getDocsFromCache()" freshness of data not guaranteed, well depending on the type of data, it may be a good idea to retrieve fresh data systematically or save a timestamp when the last real request has been made and switch from cache to network accordingly.

I want something like tanstack query i mean the behaviour should be like that the data should be loaded only once and then whenerver i navigate to the same page it should not show me the hard loading state instead the content should be like the native content preloaded, what I am trying to do is more about customising the caching accordingly for me and not about the firebase cache behaviour i should not use that if I want a behaviour like this because as I have learnt from the doc of firebase there it is clearly mentioned that firebase cache is more about offline support right explian please

You can also use react query, which is fairly easy to learn, and is basically independent of the way you retrieve data (firestore client sdk, axios, fetch). All you need to do is wrap the actions in functions that will be passed as callbacks to react query.
The easiest way to do this is to find examples like :
https://refine.dev/blog/react-query-guide/#introduction
and read the documentation if your use case doesn't fit.
Take the time to follow the examples if you don't understand, open a new post with the right subject and mention it here, I'll try to help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78333331/how-to-use-tanstack-query-in-sync-with-firebase-firestore-to-leverage-the-featur
