How to use tanstack query in sync with firebase firestore to leverage the features of tanstack query
Actually, I am a newbie to Firebase as well as to react query I can do basic stuff with them you can say that I can tell how things are working in both of them, and to a extent i can implement both averagely in projects sometimes I need help for few things and this is one of that case here I want to leverage the cache feature of tanstack query with data that I am getting through firestore manually I don't want to use a library like react query firebase or something like that I want to use it manually just for caching purpose so is there anyone who can help?
I have tried chatgpt Gemini and some amount of custom code also I searched on GitHub for some boilerplate but they are too old and I am feeling unable to understand them completely also tried to google it and got some blogs but they are either difficult to understand or you can say most of them are old

I give you an exemple with your data in the other post.
That use a function who call a query to firestore and return data
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
const queryClient = new QueryClient();
root.render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <App />
  </QueryClientProvider>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Profile />
      {/* other components rendered */}
    </>
  );
};
function Profile() {
  //My custom hook that I created to access the firebase settings and all its functions that i created or are precreated
  const firebase = useFirebase();
  const db = firebase.firestore;
  const userRef = collection(db, "users");
  const userEmail = firebase.user?.email ?? null;
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const getProfileData = async () => {
    let data = { user: null, docId: null };

    if (!userEmail) {
      //no user
      return data;
    }
    const query = query(userRef, where("Email", "==", userEmail));
    try {
      const querySnap = await getDocs(query);
      if (querySnap.empty()) {
        // no documents find
        return data;
      }
      querySnap.forEach((doc) => {
        data.user = doc.data();
        data.docId = doc.id;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      //I thinks if error throwed react-query catch them but may be
      throw error;
    }
    return data;
  };
  //staleTime con
  const { isPending, error, data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["userInfos"],
    queryFn: getProfileData,
    staleTime: 10 * 60 * 1000,
    initialData: () => {
      return queryClient.getQueryData(["userInfos"])?.data ?? undefined;
    },
  });
  //data loading
  if (isPending) return "Loading...";
  //error
  if (error) return "An error has occurred: " + error.message;
  //data is here
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.dsiplayName}</h1>
      <p>{data.email}</p>
    </div>
  );
}


I thinks you need to seen video and more exemple for understand how work the caching rules and invalidation data in react query.

Thank you Pierre I am feeling great now after resolving it customly although your orginal code does not was fitting for me but finally i pointed out how to use you code as base to solve my problem I was doing everything good but has only one problem i had not builded the query i mean i know it's a very bad mistake also I was fetching the data from the snapshot without any query and that's why I am also getting error like query not defined but yeah now I am feeling really great thanks once again

it would be great if I can get in touch with you more closely is that possible Pierre please i mean i want to learn more about coding and other stuff in depth and then get a great carrier if possible then please tell me social media reddit or discord or anything else  also you will one of my first network peer please Pierre please and  thanks once again
